# R: strptime() and is.na () unexpected results

Tags: r, datetime, strptime

I have a data frame with roughly 8 million rows and 3 columns.  I used `strptime()` in the following manner:

```
df$date.time <- strptime(df$date.time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This works fine for all but 1104 of the rows, which I checked using

```
df[is.na(df$date.time), ]
```

When I look at these "problem" data, the `date.time` entries seem to be formatted in the way I would expect.  For example, here is an observation that comes up as a problem, but doesn't appear to be an NA:

```
id                date.time              outcome
observation543490 2012-03-11 02:14:01    C
```

What could possibly be going on here that `is.na(df$date.time)` returns a TRUE value for this row that has apparently been converted correctly?

Here's a reproducible example (if you're in CST):

```
is.na(strptime("03/11/12 2:14:01 AM", "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p", "CST6CDT"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is likely that all the times that return `NA` do not exist in whatever timezone you're using, due to daylight saving time.

Check with the data source to determine the timezone the data were recorded in, then set the `tz` argument to that value in your call to `strptime`.